# Cannot read property 'createUserWithEmailAndPassword' of undefined

Tags: javascript, react-native, firebase-authentication

I got this error Cannot read property 'createUserWithEmailAndPassword' of undefined while using Firebase version 9.1.2. I have read the Firebase implementation for that I copied the code exactly for the version I use.

here's the error:

> ERROR  TypeError: Cannot read property 'createUserWithEmailAndPassword' of undefined, js engine: hermes

[image]

This is my register code:

```
import {ScrollView, StyleSheet, View} from 'react-native';
import {useState} from 'react';
import React from 'react';
import {Button, Gap, Header, Input, Loading} from '../../components';
import {colors, useForm} from '../../utils';
import {createUserWithEmailAndPassword} from 'firebase/auth';
import {fireAuth} from '../../config';
import {getDatabase, ref, set} from 'firebase/database';
import {showMessage} from 'react-native-flash-message';

export default function Register({navigation}) {
  const [form, setForm] = useForm({
    fullName: '',
    job: '',
    email: '',
    pass: '',
  });

  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);

  const onContinue = () => {
    console.log(form);
    setLoading(true);
    createUserWithEmailAndPassword(fireAuth, form.email, form.pass)
      .then(success => {
        setForm('reset');
        setLoading(false);
        const data = {
          fullName: form.fullName,
          job: form.job,
          email: form.email,
        };
        set(ref(getDatabase(), 'users/' + success.user.uid + '/'), data);
      })
      .catch(error => {
        const errorMessage = error.message;
        setLoading(false);
        showMessage({
          message: errorMessage,
          backgroundColor: colors.error,
          color: colors.white,
        });
        console.log('register error : ', errorMessage);
      });
```

This is my firebase config :

```
import { initializeApp } from 'firebase/app';
import { getAuth } from 'firebase/auth';

const firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: '',
  authDomain: '',
  projectId: '',
  storageBucket: '',
  messagingSenderId: '',
  appId: '',
  measurementId: '',
};

const fireApp = initializeApp(firebaseConfig);
export const fireAuth = getAuth(fireApp);
```

I don't understand this issue. Any suggestion?

Comment: Could you please [edit] your question to include the full error and stack trace? The error message doesn't seem to match your code

Comment: done,but the error only appears like that

Comment: I find it hard to believe it wouldn't even give you a line-of-code reference. Could you take a screenshot of the error to show it in context?

Comment: here : https://pasteboard.co/MlIWtqxJawcn.png

Comment: How have you installed `firebase` into your project? Is it through `npm` / `yarn` or are you using something different?

Comment: Also, you've tagged this with [tag:react-native-firebase] but you don't appear to be [using that](https://rnfirebase.io/auth/usage#emailpassword-sign-in). Please clarify exactly what you **are** using.

Comment: i installed via npm

Answer (score 0):

Try using this:

Initialize auth in the function `onContinue` like this:

```
const auth = getAuth();
```

And then call `auth` in `createUserWithEmailAndPassword` like this:

```
createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, form.email, form.pass)
```

This all will look like this:

```
const onContinue = () => {
    ...
    ...
    const auth = getAuth();
    createUserWithEmailAndPassword(auth, form.email, form.pass)
    ...
    ...
    ...
};
```

This has always worked for me.

I got the reference from [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/password-auth)

Comment: This is functionally identical to OP's current code

Comment: Sorry, but what does OP stand for?

Comment: Original Poster, aka the author of the question. See [What does OP mean?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/146513/158281)

Comment: Have you tried my code

Comment: i've tried your code but it gives me this error TypeError: Cannot read property 'getAuth' of undefined. i think this problem not from my code but from the firebase